# Prove that there exists a unique linear map that extends the map from a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, proof-explanation, transformation

My professor has stated the following lemma:

Let $U$ and $V$ be two vector spaces and $B$ a basis for $U$. If $f:B\rightarrow V$ is a map, then there exists a unique linear map $A: U \rightarrow V$ such that $A(x)=f(x)\ \forall\ x\in B$

How can I prove this lemma? (This is *not* a homework problem.)

Comment: So far all 3 posts of you have been problem-statement questions. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Using the definition of basis, you know any $u \in U$ can be written as a *unique linear* combination of elements of $B$. Given that you already have a map defined on $B$, does this give you a way to define *some* (linear!) function on $V$?

That is: You have $f(b_i)$ defined for $b_i \in B$. How would you define $f(\sum \alpha_ib_i)$?
(Keep in mind that you need linearity. So this would actually be forced.)

Why will this be well-defined?

Once you've defined this function, can you prove that this is indeed linear? Why must it be unique? (What if you extended $f$ in another way? Can two different linear functions agree on all basis elements?)

Comment: Due to the linearity, I can write the map of a vector $u\in U$ from $U\rightarrow V$ as
$$A(u)=A\left(\sum_{i} \alpha_{i} b_{i}\right)=\sum_{i} \alpha_{i} A\left(b_{i}\right)$$
Since the coordinates $\alpha_i$ with respect to $B$ are unique for a given vector $u$ is this enough to say that the map $A$ is unique?

Comment: "Due to the linearity", you shouldn't say that because you don't yet know whether $A$ is linear. But your idea is correct that since you want $A$ to be linear, it is reasonable to define $A(u)$ in that manner. However, the uniqueness of $\alpha_i$ only tells you that the map $A$ is well-defined. (You then will have to prove that this is indeed a linear map.) To argue for uniqueness, you would have to consider another map $A'$ such that $A'(b_i) = A(b_i) = f(b_i)$ and then show that $A(u) = A'(u)$ which will follow from linearity. (For this part, you don't need $B$ is a basis, just spanning.)

Comment: Instead of "reasonable", we can actually say that *if* $A$ were to be linear, then $$A(u) = \sum_i\alpha_iA(b_i).$$ Of course, this doesn't show that a map $A$ defined in this way *is* actually linear.